# How do I export media to my wordpress media library using Ajax?

Tags: wordpress

I would like to upload few media files to my wordpress media library via a HTTP post request. How would I go about achieving that?

Comment: Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you already tried yourself to find the problem? Questions should show **evidence of research and attempts to solve the problem yourself**, a clear outline of your specific coding-related issue, and any relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we can help.

Comment: Well, I am fairly new to WP. I have researched but it looks like you understand the question. I have to build an Ajax handler to upload files from my local computer to my wordpress site. So, if you have any clean way, much appreciated. @FluffyKitten

Comment: Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as I suggested in my first comment. Questions asking for general help are off topic for this site.